# Wordpress function cache_users not found after update to 6.1

Tags: php, wordpress, upgrade, wordpress-6

I am getting error while running a function get_users() in my custom plugin

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cache_users() in /Users/priyankgohil/sites/upw-new/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php:843

Stack trace:
#0 /Users/priyankgohil/sites/upw-new/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php(79): WP_User_Query->query()
#1 /Users/priyankgohil/sites/upw-new/wp-includes/user.php(763): WP_User_Query->__construct(Array)
#2 /Users/priyankgohil/sites/upw-new/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/Inc/BaseController.php(214): get_users(Array)

is anyone have solution or facing same issue after upgrade to wordpress 6.1

Comment: The function should get declared in pluggable.php, https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/65cdec186bc58b25258625f9db8e4a1c90aeb985/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L115 - check if yours contains that same code as it should, according to the repository.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the reply, I had checked the file and the function is there, this is only with wordpress updated to 6.1, before 6.1 it's working fine for me

Comment: Are you running your code very early, before WordPress has fully loaded?

Comment: There is a bug ticket tracking this that you might want to follow: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/56952

Answer (score 5):

Until this gets fixed, you can add the following above line 843 of wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'cache_users' ) ) {
    require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php';
}
```

This function looks like it was introduced in the new version, and the code (in other areas) appears to check for functions within pluggable.php before requiring the file.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, applied this solution.

Comment: That's not good practice at all, there is no point in modifying wordpress core file just to fix this, instead include this pluggable in your cutom plugin/code where your function is broken. This function is not new, it's already in lower versions too

Comment: Safer approach mentioned above that uses a must-use plugin to avoid modifying WP core files

Answer (score 2):

It can be patched from a must-use plugin. Add a new file at `/wp-content/mu-plugins/cache-users.php` and add this to it:

```
<?php
/**
 * cache_users() Polyfill
 *
 * Patch for issues with WP_User_Query in WP 6.1
 */
if ( ! function_exists( 'cache_users' ) ) {
  function cache_users( $results ) {
    return $results;
  }
}
```

That will safely patch the issue without modifying the WordPress core files until it's resolved in a follow-up release. It's bypassing the cache which isn't ideal, but it resolves any fatal errors reliably.

Answer (score 1):

To include the fix in your own plugin code, try this (worked for me)

```
add_action('pre_get_users','fix_cache_users_bug');

function fix_cache_users_bug($query) {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'cache_users' ) ) {
        require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/pluggable.php';
    }   
}
```

I'd suggests that's better than hacking core files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in the following way:

1. Download latest wordpress file from https://wordpress.org/download/
2. Zip all files & folders except wp-content folder and wp-config.php file [image: selected files & folder to be zipped]
3. upload zipped file created at step 2 to root directory of site
4. Unzip and replace all files and folders

I made a video on Youtube hope it can help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uTs0WBOOMew

Comment: I tried this, but not working as expected

Comment: what happens there after doing those steps?