# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cache_users()

Tags: wordpress

Error on the site under cms wordpress.
The site just suddenly stopped working.

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function cache_users() in /www/wwwroot/beavers-auto.com/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php:843 Stack trace: 
#0 /www/wwwroot/beavers-auto.com/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php(79): WP_User_Query->query() 
#1 /www/wwwroot/beavers-auto.com/wp-includes/user.php(763): WP_User_Query->__construct() 
#2 /www/wwwroot/beavers-auto.com/wp-content/plugins/stm-post-type/stm-post-type.php(281): get_users() 
#3 /www/wwwroot/beavers-auto.com/wp-settings.php(447): include_once('...') 
#4 /www/wwwroot/beavers-auto.com/wp-config.php(84): require_once('...') 
#5 /www/wwwroot/beavers-auto.com/wp-load.php(50): require_once('...') 
#6 /www/wwwroot/beavers-auto.com/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('...') 
#7 /www/wwwroot/beavers-auto.com/index.php(17): require('...') 
#8 {main} thrown in /www/wwwroot/beavers-auto.com/wp-includes/class-wp-user-query.php on line 843
```

Nothing happens when changing the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74289047/wordpress-function-cache-users-not-found-after-update-to-6-1

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a plugin conflict. You should uninstall plugins one by one to see which one is causing the problem and you should probably start with stm-post-type plugin.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Update the stm-post-type plugin to 4.8.5, this is solved there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).